# Video won't play with Android's native MediaPlayer, however it plays with Dropbox's video player

Tags: android, ffmpeg, video-streaming, media-player, dropbox

I'm having trouble playing a certain .3gp file (from a Dropbox link) with Android's MediaPlayer. However the file magically plays without problems from the Dropbox Android app.

I'm trying to play it using this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://www.dropbox.com/s/zpiqwmxka6llavt/SketchyFile.3gp"));
startActivity(intent);
```

and my manifest contains

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

which gives a "Can't play this video" error.

[image: error-screenshot]

Logcat shows:

```
I/NuCachedSource2(89): new range: offset= 2245017
I/ChromiumHTTPDataSource(89): connect to https://dl.dropbox.com/0/view/a1crokuhpprsaeo/SketchyFile.3gp @2245017
I/NuCachedSource2(89): ERROR_END_OF_STREAM
E/MediaPlayer(3629): error (1, -2147483648)
E/MediaPlayer(3629): Error (1,-2147483648)
D/VideoView(3629): Error: 1,-2147483648
```

If I try to play it from the Dropbox Android app, Dropbox's video player has no problem playing it.

[image: dropbox-success-screenshot]

According to ffmpeg's ffprobe tool I could verify that the media type is not something exotic to Android.

Is Dropbox performing some weird transcoding voodoo and is there a way I can make this work in a similar way?

EDIT: Here's some more [insight into DropBox's encoding voodoo](https://tech.dropbox.com/2014/02/video-processing-at-dropbox/).

Comment: Can you play the video straight of the SD card?

Comment: Any chance it is simply an authentication problem, ie, that the video is not public and so is accessible to the dropbox app since it is signed in, but not as a raw url handed off to another Android component which has no dropbox login session?

Comment: Unlikely, since I deliberately made the video public and can access it from a fresh browser session. There seems to be a URL redirection involved (the dropbox URL in logcat is different) but setting it to either of them makes no difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I neither have the drop box app source or access to the actual file here is my best case guess that I will make on basis of a couple of assumptions.

The file is not playable by the native app because it is in a format that cannot be played there. Can you say download the file, put it in a sd card and then play it? If not, then the phone does not support this format.

Why does dropbox player play it? My guess based on same assumption is that drop box player adds its own decoding library (eg. ffmpeg ) along with it below the jni. So it can decode this.

Another possible guess:
You are trying to do a streaming play of 3gp file which is not possible.HTTP pd play may be possible. Again, download it and play it from sd card, if it plays, then probably this is the issue.
This file may not be hinted which it needs to be.

Drop box is playing this because perhaps the dropbox app is somehow accessing the header which is at end of file (your voodoo) through some other api?

Again both of the above are guesses from common problems i see as I neither have the dropbox app source, access to your file or know exactly how you are trying to play the video using native player.Perhaps one of the above tips help. Good luck!

EDIT: Issue seen: Nexus S does not play given file locally or from http link. Turns out remuxing to mp4 made Nexus S play it both ways. This implies 3gp support is not there in local native player in some android devices.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'm going to chalk it up to Dropbox voodoo as well. I deliberately made the video file public for further analysis, is it not accessible? https://www.dropbox.com/s/zpiqwmxka6llavt/SketchyFile.3gp

Comment: Have you tryed playing it from your local sd card? Download it to your phone and play it. If you are trying to do streaming on a 3gp, it won't work. The file is accessible. It is not hinted. So it may need hinting if you are doing Pseudo streaming. Trying to play a http link with 3gp file will not work if 3gp file is not hinted and player does not support pseudo streaming.

Comment: Playing it locally from the SD card was inconclusive, it played on a Galaxy S2 but not on a Nexus S (however it played on both using dropbox). 

Your last comment put me on the right track though. It seems that the file is inside a mov container and not an mp4 one, which as far as I can see cannot be reliably streamed over http.

Comment: Nachi, even a mp4 cannot be streamed unless it is Pseudo streaming. I think your problem is that it is not hinted.

Comment: BTw, Nexus S does not play it with native player, I can confirm too. If remuxed to mp4 file, it plays from sd card and as a http link from another server (both of which were not possible earlier.) This simply means your drop box app has native support for 3gp which natvie player does not have.

Comment: Awesome! What ffmpeg parameters did you use?

Answer (score -1):

You can Use `try-catch` like follows :

```
try
{
  VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);         
  MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
  mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
  // Set Audio/Video
  String strfilename = "http://example.com/video.mp4";
  Uri video = Uri.parse(strfilename);
  videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
  videoView.setVideoURI(video);
  videoView.start();   
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{
  //enter code here
  //Handle Errors
}
```